# Does streamplot in Python matplotlib care about the order of coordinates?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to use the streamplot function in matplotlib with coordinates x, p in the order as in the code below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

size = 2
x, p = np.mgrid[-size:size:100j, -size:size:100j]

x_force = p
p_force = x**3

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
ax.streamplot(x, p, x_force, p_force, density=[0.5, 1])
plt.show()
```

This produces an error: `ValueError: The rows of 'x' must be equal`.
Quite surprisingly, changing the order of x and p in the streamplot solves the problem.

```
ax.streamplot(p, x, p_force, x_force, density=[0.5, 1])
```

Why does this happen please? How can I make the plot with coordinates in my chosen order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the order of x and p in the meshgrid command solves the problem:

```
p, x = np.mgrid[-size:size:100j, -size:size:100j]
```